# dynamic type casting of objects in C#.net

Tags: c#

I have created a `class student` and in that class `contact` object is created (aggregation). I am retrieving all stored objects in "object" array.

If I want to access `student` attribute I have to type cast it with `student` and if I want to access `contact` attribute either I have to give full path (`student_object.contact_object.attribute_name`) or simply type cast with `contact` and get the attribute value.

I have stuck at two places:

1. If I accept class name
   from user and then want to access
   the value. How can I do that? How to
   type cast with textbox variable.
2. If field name I accept
   from user in text box . How can I
   access the value using text box
   variable?

Jon,
   Actually I have created a object oriented database in C#.NET. where above classes are there. I am Retrieving all objects in Object array. Class student has field name and age , while contact has mobileID . Now I am creating a query through textboxes. If user want to see name of all the object , then var2 name he shold put. but i am not able to get this message
 messageBox.show(o0 as Student).var2);
Same if instead of Student if I give var1
messageBox.show(o0 as var1).var2);
Can I do this? 
thanks/Bharti

Answer (score 1):

Casting is important for *compile-time* information. That precludes anything that the user provides at *execution time*.

It sounds like you really need to just reflection:

```
PropertyInfo property = value.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
// Insert validation here...
object propertyValue = property.GetValue(value, null);
```

You'll need to be smarter if you want the user to be able to evaluate a *path* of properties such as `Address.ZipCode` but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: could you pl elaborate I am not getting it.

Comment: @Bharti: I've given you some sample code... have you tried it? Look at the docs for `Type.GetProperty` for some more information.

Comment: object[] obj=retrieveAllobjects("Student");

Comment: @Bharti: Please put your code in the *question* rather than in comments.

Comment: String var1=TextBox1.txt;String var2= TextBox2.txt; now if I accept var1 as a Student and var2 as name. Then I want to access like obj[0] as var1.var2. Can I do that?

Comment: @Bharti: As I said, please put code in the question rather than comments. And I've already *given* you the code to access a property by name. You don't need the type name.

Comment: @Bharti: I'm still not seeing any code in the question, and "it is not working" isn't a good description of what's happening. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Have you read the documentation for Type.GetProperty? Do you understand what the code I've given is doing?